# Remove reoccurring data from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like this:

```
data.table(a=rep(c("xx", "yy"), each=4), b=rep(c("zz", "nn"), each=2), vals=10:17)

    a  b vals
1: xx zz   10
2: xx zz   11
3: xx nn   12
4: xx nn   13
5: yy zz   14
6: yy zz   15
7: yy nn   16
8: yy nn   17
```

What i want is this, since it looks better in a table when exported to excel and then to words (I know, never use excel...):

```
    a  b vals
1: xx zz   10
2: NA NA   11
3: NA nn   12
4: NA NA   13
5: yy zz   14
6: NA NA   15
7: NA nn   16
8: NA NA   17
```

EDIT: forgot to say that if a numeric value is recurring, it should not be changed to NA, only character columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `rleid` from `data.table` we can create a function

```
library(data.table)

replace_duplicated <- function(x) {
  replace(x, duplicated(rleid(x)), NA)
}
```

and now apply it to selected columns (Thanks to @markus)

```
cols = names(df)[sapply(df, is.character)]
df[,(cols) := lapply(.SD, replace_duplicated ), .SDcols = cols]
df

#      a    b vals
#1:   xx   zz   10
#2: <NA> <NA>   11
#3: <NA>   nn   12
#4: <NA> <NA>   13
#5:   yy   zz   14
#6: <NA> <NA>   15
#7: <NA>   nn   16
#8: <NA> <NA>   17
```

---

In `dplyr` we can use `mutate_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.character, replace_duplicated)
```

or `mutate_at`

```
df %>% mutate_at(cols, replace_duplicated)
```

Comment: nice. I can see in my data it should only do it in character columns, so that values don't get NA'ed. Could this be done also?

Comment: @Ronak You could also add a `data.table` way `df[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(rleid(x)), NA))]`

Comment: OP wants to keep the last column as is, in case there are duplicated numbers.

Comment: @zx8754 Had included `mutate_if` option for that earlier, now also added `data.table` option.

Comment: Great! If I may suggest, put the data.table solution at the top, as the OP is tagged with data.table, not dplyr.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `set` from `data.table` to update by reference

```
nm1 <- names(dt)[1:2]
for(j in nm1) set(dt, i = which(duplicated(rleid(dt[[j]]))), j = j, value = NA)
dt
#      a    b vals
#1:   xx   zz   10
#2: <NA> <NA>   11
#3: <NA>   nn   12
#4: <NA> <NA>   13
#5:   yy   zz   14
#6: <NA> <NA>   15
#7: <NA>   nn   16
#8: <NA> <NA>   17
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding another method using `shift` and some timings for reference:

```
set.seed(0L)
sz <- 1e7
DT <- data.table(a=sample(LETTERS, sz, TRUE), b=sample(LETTERS, sz, TRUE))
#DT <- data.table(a=rep(c("xx", "yy"), each=4), b=rep(c("zz", "nn"), each=2), vals=10:17)
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)

cols <- c("a","b")


mtd0 <- function() {
    DT[,(cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) 
        replace(x, duplicated(rleid(x)), NA_character_)) , .SDcols = cols]
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    for(j in cols) 
        set(DT1, i=DT1[, which(get(j)==shift(get(j), 1L))], j=j, value=NA_character_)
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    for(j in cols) 
        set(DT2, i=which(duplicated(rleid(DT2[[j]]))), j=j, value=NA_character_)
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2(), times=3L)

identical(DT, DT1)
#[1] TRUE

identical(DT1, DT2)
#[1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 mtd0() 1372.4244 1405.1756 1448.8020 1437.9269 1486.9909 1536.0549     3   b
 mtd1()  280.7695  281.2639  305.5433  281.7583  317.9303  354.1022     3  a 
 mtd2() 1200.5236 1224.5174 1339.0146 1248.5112 1408.2601 1568.0090     3   b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a quick loop:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rep(c("xx", "yy"), each=4), b=rep(c("zz", "nn"), each=2), vals=10:17)

for(i in 1:2){
  df[,i][duplicated(df[,i])] <-NA
}
```